# Need help with db.transaction in javascript function.... is there a delay?

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have this code in a JavaScript file:

```
function getProvincialStandardForRace(seedAge, seedGender, seedCourse, seedDistance, seedEvent) {

    var seedAge;
    var seedGender;
    var seedCourse;
    var seedDistance;
    var seedEvent;
    // Declare SQL database variables
    var shortName = 'SwimChamp';
    var version = '1.0';
    var displayName = 'SwimChamp';
    var maxSize = 5*1024*1024;
    var db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);

    db.transaction (
        function(transaction) {
            transaction.executeSql(
                'SELECT * FROM standards WHERE (age=? AND gender=? AND course=? AND distance=? AND event=?);',
                [seedAge, seedGender, seedCourse, seedDistance, seedEvent],
                function(transaction, result) {
                    localStorage.standardRetrieved = result.rows.item(0)['provstandard'];   
                    console.log(localStorage.standardRetrieved);
                }
            );
        }
    );
    console.log(localStorage.standardRetrieved);
}
```

Why does the second `console.log`, the one outside the `db.transaction`, actually execute before the `console.log` inside my success function?

I'm completely perplexed. It looks like there's a delay in executing the `db.transaction`, and code after the `db.transaction` executes first, then the `db.transaction` finishes last.

Answer (score 0):

Your function inside the executeSql function is a callback for when the sql executes and that the executeSql function is asynchronous. So the executeSql function returns immediately, the second console.log function is called, executeSql function finishes and calls the first console.log.

Comment: Thanks @joekarl - I've been stumped!  So my problem is that the function returns to a web page with an old value and then the new value is found asynchronously but it's too late.  So I end up seeing an old value returned to the user.  Can you please suggest a fix so that the function returns with the newest value?

Comment: I've tried setting a variable = 0 and then only set it to 1 once the executeSql function is successful.  Then I tried a for loop on my .html page to wait until the but now my html page hangs and the Safari browser says that there's a slow script.  I take the for look out and everything runs, but incorrectly due to the asynchronous issue. Help!?